# .NET 4.x TextBox. Ввод только цифр от 16 до 100 - C# WPF

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения, wpf, textbox

задача: ввод только цифр от 16 до 100
 как можно регулярным выражением сделать от 16-100, или может еще какой способ есть?

```
Regex inputRegex = new Regex(@"^[16-100]$"); //так не работает!
```

Comment: Цифра — это символ от нуля до девяти. А регулярные выражения созданы для поиска подстрок, для ввода числа ограниченного диапазона лучше подходят приведение к нужному размеру, циклический ввод до подходящего значения или другие ухищрения, которые посоветуют знатоки.

Comment: В каком смысле «так не работает»? Вы создали регулярку, и она почему-то не применилась магическим образом к тексту?

Comment: @VladD Просто регулярка не работает потому что она в корне ошибочка.

Comment: @vitidev: Это да, но в вопросе нету обвязки, поэтому я рискнул предположить, что её нет вовсе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

диалекты движков регулярных выражений, конечно, могут отличаться.

вот решение «в лоб» для extended regular expression:

```
^(1[6-9]|[2-9][0-9]|100)$
```

скобками ограничены три варианта, варианты разделены между собой символами <kbd>|</kbd>:

```
1[6-9]
[2-9][0-9]
100
```

первый вариант: символ `1`, за которым следует любой из символов из диапазона `6-9`.

второй вариант: любой из символов из диапазона `2-9`, за которым следует любой из символов из диапазона `0-9`.

третий вариант: просто три символа `100`.